# Why google code download page have a QR code?

Tags: encoding, qr-code, google-code

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [QR Codes for Files on Google Code](https://superuser.com/questions/140848/qr-codes-for-files-on-google-code)

When I open a google code download page, there is a QR code at the bottom.
What kind of devices will read this human unreadable QR code?
I cannot figure out why google put a QR code there.
If such a device is so powerful to recognize this image,
why it's cannot just read the ascii text in the page?
I really don't know the purpose.

http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chs=150x150&cht=qr&chl=http://recaptcha.googlecode.com/files/recaptcha-dotnet-1.0.3.0-binary.zip&chld=L|1&choe=UTF-8
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try copying the URL from your address bar to your mobile phone manually and you'll quickly see the benefit of the QR code.